# SQL Optimization: exceeded call limit on CPU usage

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

Looking for help optimizing the below query. The goal is to get a count of the a.subscriber_no that fall into each bucket based on their tbl1.duration (contract duration 0 / 24/ 1-23 / >24). I can run the query without the COUNT and it pulls 22 million records, with the COUNT I get error: ORA-02393: exceeded call limit on CPU usage. Any ideas on how to optimize / work around this? Have been googling/ re-writing this for days.

````
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN tbl1.duration = 0 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "0 term",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN tbl1.duration = 24 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "24 term",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN tbl1.duration between 1 and 23 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "term >0 and <24",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN tbl1.duration > 24 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "term > 24"
from  
    (Select
    a.subscriber_no,
    max(b.commit_start_date),
    max(b.commit_end_date),
    round (months_between(to_date(max(b.commit_end_date)),to_date(max(b.commit_start_date))),0) as duration,
    max(b.EFFECTIVE_DATE)
    from sales a
    join contract b on a.subscriber_no = b.subscriber_no
    join subscriber c on a.subscriber_no = c.subscriber_no
    where a.type = 'F'
    and c.sub_status = 'Y'
    group by
    a.subscriber_no) tbl1;```
````

Comment: I assume you have all the correct indexes in place? And depending on the number of rows excluded by the to where clauses, you might be better to do split it into multiple parts, maybe using CTEs, so that all the grouping can be done on the Contract table by itself, which might be satisfied entirely out of a suitable index.

Comment: How long does it take before the query throws that error?  From the query, it looks like you're doing something that will inevitably have to read a large percentage of rows, and may always be kind of slow.  Your system is set up to prevent long-running queries, which might make sense for a website user, but may not be right for your account.  Find your profile from `select profile, username from dba_users;`, and compare it with other profiles from `select * from dba_profiles;`  You may need to change your accounts profile.